# Issue when using document.querySelectorAll() on a span within an option inside a select

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a web project and I've encountered an issue when trying to select `span` elements that are within `option` elements inside a `select` using document.querySelectorAll() in JavaScript.

```js
const currencySpans = document.querySelectorAll('.amount-currency-span span');

console.log(currencySpans);
```

```html
<select id="movie">
  <option value="10" class="amount-currency-span">Avengers: Endgame (<span class="amount-currency-span">10USD</span>)</option>
  <option value="12" class="amount-currency-span">Joker (<span class="amount-currency-span">12USD</span>)</option>
  <option value="8" class="amount-currency-span">Toy Story 4 (<span class="amount-currency-span">8USD</span>)</option>
  <option value="9" class="amount-currency-span">The Lion King (<span class="amount-currency-span">9USD</span>)</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that currencySpans is empty, and I'm not sure why. Can someone explain why `document.querySelectorAll('.amount-currency-span span')` is not selecting the span elements within the select options? Is there something I'm missing or doing incorrectly?

I greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have span elements within the option elements.

[Option elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element) are only allowed to contain text (i.e. *not* other elements).

> Content model:
> If the element has a label attribute and a value attribute: Nothing.
> If the element has a label attribute but no value attribute: Text.
> If the element has no label attribute and is not a child of a datalist element: Text that is not inter-element whitespace.
> If the element has no label attribute and is a child of a datalist element: Text.

If you examine the DOM using your browser's Element Inspector, you'll see that the spans have been discarded as the browser recovered from your error.

[image]